# Bit mask in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What is the best way to construct a bit mask in C with `m` set bits preceded by `k` unset bits, and followed by `n` unset bits:

```
00..0 11..1 00..0
  k     m     n
```

For example, k=1, m=4, n=3 would result in the bit mask:

```
01111000
```

Comment: For answers to many bit twiddling hacks, such as this, a very good online source is [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html).

Comment: Customarily, a bitmask macros are defined on *inclusive* bit indices, something like `#define BITS(p,q) ...` where p = m + n - 1 and q = n, p >= q

Comment: [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) is far more comprehensive (1.8 kilopages) and awesome.

Comment: @grigy I don't really understand why you need to have `k` in here. It's just easier to specify a range of bits to set using `m` and `n` only.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can do:

```
~(~0 << m) << n
```

Comment: This is slick.  However, It would be a good idea to comment this line, for the -next- programmer to work on it.

Comment: If this was coded as a function (the set_mask_n functions in @quinmar's answer), there'd be a one-line comment saying what the function does (and no argument 'k'), and users of the function would have the name as documentation.  As a random expression in a bit of code, it would indubitably be BAD!

Comment: And, I would hasten (very slowly) to add, my solution would be equally inscrutable if it appeared as an uncommented expression in a bit of code.

Comment: The `~(~0 << m)` is in paragraph 2.9 "Bitwise Operators" of "The C Programming Language, second edition" by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie. It is also in paragraph 7.5 "Space Efficiency" of "The Practice of Programming" by Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike.

Comment: This approach *cannot* create a mask including the *top-most bit* of the *longest unsigned integer type*, i.e., usually indicated with a warning like `integer overflow in preprocessor expression`.

Comment: @Barry, I'm having trouble seeing the problem, doubtless because it's been many years since I looked at the standard (and an older one at that). With gcc -Wall --ansi --pedantic on "~(~0 << 1) << 31" I get no such warning (and I do get a different one on bumping 31 to 32, so this is a test with 32-bit numbers).

Comment: @DariusBacon I have found that the answer below causes gcc to complain about integer overflow i.e `printf("%u\n", ((1 << 31) - 1) << 0);` generates `warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]`. I also agree with Barry that the bitmask does not set the MSB of an unsigned integer. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: This should be `~(~0u << m) << n`.

Answer (score 29):

So, you are asking for m set bits prefixed by k reset bits and followed by n reset bits?  We can ignore k since it will largely be constrained by the choice of integer type.

```
mask = ((1 << m) - 1) << n;
```

Comment: They both work but I find Jonathan's answer to be simpler and clearer. Darius' answer is a little too backwards to me.

Comment: Robert, I like the ~0 idiom for bitmasks because it doesn't depend on 2's-complement, and is in that sense simpler, but it's true it's less well-known. Just doing my bit to change that!

Comment: @Darius: if you are using unsigned arithmetic/types, as you should in these contexts, isn't the difference between 2's-complement, 1's-complement and sign-magnitude arithmetic immaterial?

Comment: @Darius, you shouldn't be performing bitwise arithmetic on signed types in the first place and if you were, your solution invokes undefined behavior every time!

Comment: Is it undefined? I dont have spec at hand, but I think it is implementation defined, i.e. the compiler is allowed to do it like he wants, but he must always do it the same way. So when you know the treatment (of your compiler) you can rely on it.

Comment: C99 §6.5.7p4: "The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; [...] If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 * 2 ^ E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: I was wrong to say 2's-complement. Properly, what's simpler is that the ~0 code uses only shifts and individual-bit operations, not arithmetic depending on details of number representation. This is natural for what bitmasks are for. It's admittedly not worth confusing anyone over.

Comment: (continued) So (1<<m)-1 seems more surprising, if you come to it with fresh eyes, which we mostly don't.

Comment: @Darius: maybe your best shot is: if the integers are 32-bits and m = 32, then the behaviour of my expression is undefined (6.5.7, para 3 in C99).  And I don't think I could refute that claim.

Comment: @Darius: continuing - however, the same argument can be used against yours...oh well.  This is as near a tie as anything ever can be.  Congratulations on getting there first.

Comment: I think yours might be a jot faster, Jonathan. (Haven't tested.) Honestly, I'm not a zealot in the grand ~0 cause -- it's funny how the littlest things start the longest threads.

Comment: @Darius: counting basic operations: both solutions have two shifts, by the same amounts; yours has one active '~' operation versus mine has one '-' operation (the '~0' is evaluated by the compiler, of course). Both expressions should have the same speed.

Comment: Yes, I had two speculative reasons in mind: ~0 is a more expensive constant than 1 on an architecture without a sign-extended constant-load operation, and a compiler that for some reason can take advantage of recognizing this idiom is more likely to look for the better-known one (yours).

Answer (score 5):

I like both solutions.  Here is another way that comes to my mind (probably not better).

`((~((unsigned int)0) << k) >> (k + n)) << n`

EDIT:
There was a bug in my previous version (it was without the unsigned int cast). The problem was that `~0 >> n` adds 1s at the front and not 0s.

And yes this approach has one big downside; it assumes that you know the number of bits of the default integer type or in other words it assumes that you really know k, whereas the other solutions are independent of k. This makes my version less portable, or at least harder to port.  (It also uses 3 shifts, and addition and a bitwise negation operator, which is two extra operations.)

**So you would do better to use one of the other examples.**

Here is a little test app, done by Jonathan Leffler, to compare and verify the output of the different solutions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

enum { ULONG_BITS = (sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT) };

static unsigned long set_mask_1(int k, int m, int n)
{
    return ~(~0 << m) << n;
}

static unsigned long set_mask_2(int k, int m, int n)
{
    return ((1 << m) - 1) << n;
}

static unsigned long set_mask_3(int k, int m, int n)
{
    return ((~((unsigned long)0) << k) >> (k + n)) << n;
}

static int test_cases[][2] =
{
    { 1, 0 },
    { 1, 1 },
    { 1, 2 },
    { 1, 3 },
    { 2, 1 },
    { 2, 2 },
    { 2, 3 },
    { 3, 4 },
    { 3, 5 },
};

int main(void)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        int m = test_cases[i][0];
        int n = test_cases[i][1];
        int k = ULONG_BITS - (m + n);
        printf("%d/%d/%d = 0x%08lX = 0x%08lX = 0x%08lX\n", k, m, n,
               set_mask_1(k, m, n),
               set_mask_2(k, m, n),
               set_mask_3(k, m, n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On the assumption that this answer can be made to work, the obvious downside in comparison with the other two is the presence of the third shift operation, which makes it more time consuming.

Comment: The other problem is that it uses the parameter k which the other two solutions are able to ignore (it doesn't use m, though, so it still only uses two of the three parameters).

Comment: Right there was a bug in it, I fixed it now and add a comment that the other solutions are preferable. I haven't removed it completely, maybe someone can learn from my mistakes and it'd be sad to loose your nice test code :).

Comment: Instead of the cast, you should be able to use '0U' to indicate an unsigned zero, or '0UL' to indicate an unsigned long.  I agree with leaving your answer in place - and with the edits you made.

Comment: Make this a macro or inline function, the compiler will generate a constant at compile-time instead of code.

Comment: @Barry, the compiler is free to 'inline' a static function and I'm sure that all modern compiler will do that in this case here.

Answer (score 2):

(Only) For those who are interested in a slightly more efficient solution on x86 systems with BMI2 support (Intel Haswell or newer, AMD Excavator or newer):

```
mask = _bzhi_u32(-1,m)<<n;
```

The `bzhi` instruction zeros the high bits starting with specified bit position.
The `_bzhi_u32` intrinsic compiles to this instruction. Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=haswell bitmsk_mn.c   */

unsigned int bitmsk(unsigned int m, unsigned int n)
{
    return _bzhi_u32(-1,m)<<n;
}

int main() {
    int k = bitmsk(7,13);
    printf("k= %08X\n",k);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$./a.out
k= 000FE000
```

The code fragment `_bzhi_u32(-1,m)<<n` compiles to three instructions

```
movl    $-1, %edx
bzhi    %edi, %edx, %edi
shlx    %esi, %edi, %eax
```

Which is one instruction less than the codes by [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316494/2439725)
and [@Darius Bacon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/316493/2439725).
On Intel Haswell processors or newer, both `bzhi` and `shlx` have a latency of 1 cycle and a 
throughput of 2 per cycle. On AMD Ryzen these two instructions even have a throughput of 4 per cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the top answers are simple and effective they don't set the MSB for the case when `n=0` and `m=31`:

`~(~0 << 31) << 0` =  ‭`0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111‬`

`((1 << 31)-1) << 0` = ‭`0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111‬`

My suggestion for a 32-bit unsigned word looks like this:

```
unsigned int create_mask(unsigned int n,unsigned int m) {
  // 0 <= start_bit, end_bit <= 31
  assert(n >=0 && m<=31);
  return (m - n == 31 ? ~0: ((1 << (m-n)+1)-1) << n);
}
```

This actually gets the bits in the range `[m,n]` (closed interval) so `create_mask(0,0)` will return a mask for the first bit (bit 0) and `create_mask(4,6)` returns a mask for bits 4 to 6 i.e `... 00111 0000`.