# combining two hex variables into short

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have two variables:

```
char a = "0xdb";
char b = "0x01";
```

How to combine these variable to short type? Like this:

```
short c = "0x01db";
```

thanks.

Comment: You should read about bit shifting and other binary operations. They're a must-know for any programmer.

Comment: There is no such thing as "hex variables"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bit mask in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316488/bit-mask-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned char a = 0xdb;
unsigned char b = 0x01;
unsigned short c = (b << 8) | a;
```

Comment: If you really must be rude to beginners, you should at least check you haven't made any mistakes yourself. You can't use a multi-token type name in a function-style cast. (Also, the casts are pointless, since everything will be promoted to `int` or similar anyway).